# C# / .NET equivalent to Python inspect

Tags: c#, python, stack-trace

I've had great luck in the past using [the inspect module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) in Python to assist in post-mortem debugging: It makes it easy to look through the stack of an error and see the local variables in each frame when something has gone wrong.

I'd like to do something similar in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) ([C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) particularly). Is there a readily available method for grabbing all of the local variables in a set of stack frames at exception time? As far as I can tell the .NET StackFrame object contains only metadata about the location of the frame in the code. I'd like to find a .NET equivalent of the `f_locals` and `f_globals` members of an inspect 'frame' object.

The ideal answer would work under [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) and .NET 2.0.

Comment: I doubt you're going to find much. After JIT-compilation, all that remains is machine code. The runtime does know how this data is structured (it has to in order to support remote debugging, for example), but I know of no managed interface by which you can obtain this information.  Is there a reason you cannot use a debugger?

Comment: It's intended for game developer QA: somebody sees something wrong and wants to log a report, it's extremely useful to get a a snapshot of the state they were seeing.

Comment: There's not anything I'm aware of in the core framework that's going to do this for you.  This level of execution detail is simply not provided.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliTrace is what you are looking for, it allows you to record stacks, exceptions and much more

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264915.aspx

EDIT:
Obviously this will not work under Mono.

The only thing i can advice there is log all exceptions and maybe look into http://www.mono-project.com/Soft_Debugger

Comment: IntelliTrace is what you want... but you have to have VS ultimate to use it.